Is there a way to print a custom progress bar in powershell
I would like to show a custom progress bar in my powershell script. It should be in the last line of the console output and the "100% Success" message should stay.
Write-Progress is nice, but it disappears when finished or if the script execution gets canceled

PowerShell is designed to leave progress rendering the responsibility of the host application (eg. powershell.exe or pwsh.exe or powershell_ise.exe or whatever else program in which you're hosting the PowerShell runtime), not script authors, so the "correct" way to do what you ask is to implement your own custom host application :)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 
$progressForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$progressForm.Size = '360,100'
$progressForm.Text = "ProgressBar"
 
$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressBar.Location = '20,20'
$progressBar.Size = '300,20'
$progressBar.Value = 100
$progressForm.Controls.Add($progressBar)
$progressForm.TabStop = $true
$progressForm.ShowDialog()


nice...........

this is certainly a nice solution, but not what I was looking for. I need the progress bar to be displayed in the console output, similar to what like winget does.

@axcro If so, your stuck with Write-Progress to avoid it from disappearing you can use a sleep or pause after Write-Progress.
